# Execute php i5 ibm commands using i5 toolkit

Tags: php, ibm-midrange

Am using i5_command for copying a file from one location to another using i5 command

CPYFRMIMPF

Am getting CPF0006 error , with error code 9.

What is the correct format of executing command.

What are the Minimum requirements for running an i5.

i5 command for connectivity is done succesfully.

rtv user profile also working.

But  copy filenot working?

Any one have any idea about PHP i5 IBM DB2 . :)

Comment: @zod I just did a Google search for your error code and my answer was the first result. There is more people using IBM i than you think there is. Any many are at least playing with PHP on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this thread](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=2281) on Zend's forums.

> Using i5_program_prepare and i5_program_call worked.

I hope that helps. I don't have much experience on PHP on IBM i.

Comment: Thanks for reply. i find some good materials here and am using this, you can also refer . :) http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Core-i5/i5_php_connector_api.htm